# NGINX - Why I am getting a 403 Forbidden for root location?

Tags: nginx, redirect, location

I developed a project with the following structure:

`api.my-domain.com`: An Restfull API built in Symfony 5.
`app.my-domain.com`: An Angular App.
`www.my-domain.com`: A simple but beautiful HTML/CSS/JS landing page.

This structure is served using NGINX on a Ubuntu server. The config files for the `api` and `app` sites are working fine. Nothing to do there.

For the `landing` one I have some custom requirements:

- I need to redirect to the `app` site the request containing "login" or "pm-".
- I need to support a multi-language site, so:

  - When someone access [www.my-domain.com/**es**](http://www.my-domain.com/**es**), the server should show index_**es**.html
  - When someone access [www.my-domain.com/**en**](http://www.my-domain.com/**en**), the server should show index_**en**.html
  - When someone access [www.my-domain.com/**ca**](http://www.my-domain.com/**ca**), the server should show index_**ca**.html
- When someone access **[www.my-domain.com](http://www.my-domain.com)**, the server should return **index_es.html**; but it should also let access the other static files on the server (images, fonts, styles...) in order to get the landings working.

This requirements are already meet using the following NGINX site config site:

```
server {
    server_name www.my-domain.com my-domain.com;
    root /var/www/my-project/;

    location = /es {
      try_files /index_es.html /index.html;
    }

    location = /en {
      try_files /index_en.html /index.html;
    }

    location = /ca {
      try_files /index_ca.html /index.html;
    }

    location = / {
      try_files /index_es.html /index.html;
    }

    location ~ ^/(login|pm-) {
      return 301 $scheme://app.my-project.com$request_uri;
    }
    
    location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index_es.html;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/my-project-error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/my-project-access.log;



    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-project.com-0001/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my-project.com-0001/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot




}
server {
    if ($host = www.my-project.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = my-project.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    server_name www.my-project.com my-project.com;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

The thing is, on my first attempt to got it working, I didn't put the following piece of code:

```
location = / {
  try_files /index_es.html /index.html;
}
```

Because I thought that it was enough specifying this:

```
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index_es.html;
}
```

But when tried to access the `www.my-domain.com` I got a 403 Forbidden page from NGINX. So, the questions are:

- Why I currently need to put the `location = /` piece of code in order to get it working?
- How can I optimize the configuration in order to remove the `location = /` piece of code?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The `$uri/` term is looking for an index file, which by default is `index.html`. If you added `index index_es.html;`, it would work as expected.

Comment: @RichardSmith Thanks for your comment. So... You mean to remove the `location = /` part, and then, define the following: location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/;
  index index_es.html;
}; right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your configuration would be much cleaner if you resorted to simple `rewrite`s directly within the `server` context:

```
server {
    server_name www.my-domain.com my-domain.com;
    root /var/www/my-project/;

    rewrite ^/(es|en|ca)$ /index_$1.html;
    
    location = / {
        index index_es.html; 
    }
    # ...
}
```

For a static website, I would recommend to completely eliminate `try_files`.
It makes sense only for dynamic websites, and [*may be evil*](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/nginx-try_files-is-evil-too).

> Why I currently need to put the location = / piece of code in order to get it working?

Because in your posted configuration, if you remove it, then for URI `/`, NGINX will select `location / {` block, which will attempt (due to `$uri/`) files defined as [`index`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_index_module.html#directives), which default to `index.html`. So it will try to check if it exists, succeed with it, and use it for serving the request.

Once you define `location = /`, NGINX will use that for serving, because exact matching type (`=`) always has priority in NGINX, over other location types.

> How can I optimize the configuration in order to remove the location = / piece of code?

You don't really need to remove `location = /` (see adjusted config above). If anything, the exact matching type is preferable, as it will result in the fastest matching. (unless you can deal with things by removing file existence checks, see below).

Someone may argue whether:

```
location = /es {
    try_files /index_es.html /index.html;
}

location = /en {
    try_files /index_en.html /index.html;
}

location = /ca {
    try_files /index_ca.html /index.html;
}
```

... would be faster than the `rewrite` suggested. It wouldn't be fast, due to `try_files` which makes things slower. Why, is because `try_files` first check a file for existence, and then makes a decision on whether to move on to the next file, or serving.

Whereas, the `rewrite` is doing unconditional decision on which file to use for serving. (of course, unless you have other directives affecting it).

You can also attempt to optimize even further by not using `index` and using `rewrite` for the homepage. (mind that `index` also bears performance penalty of file existence check, same to `try_files`).

Thus:

```
server {
    server_name www.my-domain.com my-domain.com;
    root /var/www/my-project/;

    rewrite ^/(es|en|ca)$ /index_$1.html;
    rewrite ^/$ /index_es.html; 
    # ...
}
```

Comment: Sorry, can you explain in detail, why `$uri/` will attemt to load the default index file?

Comment: Whenever NGINX tries to process a directory for serving (and `try_files` is where it first checks if directory exists), it needs to use *a file* to serve a response. There's no such thing as "serving a directory" in response (unless we look into `autoindex` module, but that's another case). NGINX needs a file to return a response. Which files are are being tried while delivering response for a directory request (`$uri/`) is controlled by `index` directive, which has the default value `index.html`.